# How to stop a timer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, widget

How do I cancel this timer?

I have made a function designed to stop the timer however it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know why?

```
  int randomNote = Random().nextInt(6);
  int randomType = Random().nextInt(6);
  Timer? timer;
  String changeTimer = 'Start Timer';

  void startTimer() {
   Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
     setState(() {
       randomNote = Random().nextInt(6);
       randomType = Random().nextInt(6);
     });
   });

  }

  void stopTimer() {
    timer?.cancel();
  }
```

*There is a button widget here*

```
onPressed: () {
                if (changeTimer == 'Start Timer') {
                  startTimer();
                  setState(() {
                    changeTimer = 'Stop Timer';
                  });
                }
                else {
                  stopTimer();
                  setState(() {
                    changeTimer = 'Start Timer';
                  });
                }
             },
```

How do I cancel this timer?

I have made a function designed to stop the timer however it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know why? I am very confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never assign your `timer` variable. Something like that should work:

```
int randomNote = Random().nextInt(6);
int randomType = Random().nextInt(6);
Timer? timer;
String changeTimer = 'Start Timer';
    
void startTimer() {
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
    setState(() {
      randomNote = Random().nextInt(6);
      randomType = Random().nextInt(6);
    });
  }); 
}
    
void stopTimer() {
  timer?.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning anything to outer `timer` variable

This should work:

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
     setState(() {
       timer = t;
       randomNote = Random().nextInt(6);
       randomType = Random().nextInt(6);
     });
   });
```

Comment: It looks like your code would work wrong if we call `stopTimer` before first timer callback invocation.

Comment: ?. operator is there to help :)

Comment: `Null` is not a problem here. The problem in your code is you assign variable inside the timer callback. It means you will not able to stop the timer until the first callback invocation. E.g. you could do it only after a second.